# My update is running WAY SLOWER than it should

Tags: c++, math, timer

I am trying to create a program that writes sheet music as you play. My first goal was to get an update cruising along at 64 times per beat (this is all the accuracy I need for my purposes). However, when I set up my code the update runs WAY SLOWER than it should.

My code is set up to run at 140 beats per minute, but it only sounds like about 50 beats per minute.

I have a theory that it is an issue with the calculating of the delay between updates, but I can't figure out what I've done wrong. Here's the entirety of my code:

```
#include <raylib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

#include "filestuff.h"

Sound metVoices[1];
int metSelectedVoice = 0;

float bpm = 140;

void initSounds() {

    using str = std::string;

    str v1p = getExeDir() + "\\sounds\\met voice 1.wav";
    metVoices[0] = LoadSound(v1p.data());
}

void update64() {

    std::cout << "64th note" << std::endl;
}

void updateBeat() {

    //PlaySound is asynchronous
    PlaySound(metVoices[metSelectedVoice]);
}

int main() {

    InitAudioDevice();
    initSounds();

    long double delay64;

    //bps and beat will clear from memory because they go out of scope
    {
        long double bps = bpm / 60;
        long double beat = 1 / bps;
        delay64 = beat / 64;
    }

    long double update64Timer = delay64;
    long double beatTimer = 64;
    long double dt = 0;

    while (true) {

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point frameStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        update64Timer -= dt;

        if (update64Timer <= 0) {

            update64();
            beatTimer--;
            update64Timer = delay64;
        }

        if (beatTimer <= 0) {

            updateBeat();
            beatTimer = 64;
        }

        dt = std::chrono::duration<long double>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - frameStart).count();
    }

    CloseAudioDevice();

    return 0;
}
```

It's been pointed out that my code is not exeption safe, and that there are some magic numbers in there. I plan on improving these things, but I need to get something working first.

If any more information is needed I will gladly share it. Thanks in advance to anybody that helps me out!

Comment: Where is `PlaySound` from? Is it synchronous ?

Comment: A loop like that is quite resource consuming, I'd use a non busy sleep (`sleep_for`, `Sleep`). Unrelated: your code is not exception safe. Avoid magic numbers. Use `const` or `constexpr` for those numeric constants.

Comment: @MatG I need my program to be as accurate as possible. Would sleep_for be just as accurate as what I have done?

Comment: @RichardCritten PlaySound is asynchronous

Comment: What were the results when you profiled your code?  Which sections are taking up the most time?

Comment: I recommend at least 2 threads.  One thread writes the data to memory (this can be used as a call back to WaitObject() or interrupt based).  The other thread runs in the background, reads memory and writes to a file.

Comment: @Dat1channels I don't know about the accuracy, measure. But since you know the time interval, you can sleep a little less and resume your angry check just a little before the expected time expiration.

Comment: Note that in music, timings don't need to be very precise. A good musician cannot be more precise than ~50ms anyway. Best is to avoid timing errors to accumulate, by using absolute time stamps. A little jitter will remain unnoticed, but even a slight difference in overall tempo can be felt by a human.

Comment: Don't use sleep, it doesn't account for the time your code uses or the time spent in other tasks.  Get your OS to send you a message on a regular basis and respond to that.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. The code was so inefficient that it could keep up with the 64 times per beat pulse.